# make an iframe loaded in app display mobile site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cordova

I have an app made with Phonegap.

For a certain feature, sometimes I need to load a webpage/ site into the app - for this, i use an iframe.

The iframe always displays the desktop version of the webpage though, even when I know the page has a responsive design.

Is there a way to force the iframe to load the site as a mobile?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [InAppBrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) plugin to open up an external web page. This is going to be much safer since the foreign page won't have access to your Cordova instance. (If I have a third party page, and you load my page into your app through an iFrame, I can easily "hack" your application and steal user data, run arbitrary Cordova commands, etc.)

Additionally, when using the InAppBrowser, you can tell the browser to open any links in the current Cordova WebView, so that external site will just appear in your app. I don't know what your external site looks like, but this might be what you want to do. You can accomplish this by setting the target as `_self`, like this:

`var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');`